# Shopify: Header navigation color changes for only homepage

Tags: css, shopify

Trying to change the color of the nav menu just for the homepage in Shopify but couldn't find any solution to it. I tried to call #MainContent(homepage) and header classes but nothing happened.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

1. Go to `Themes`
2. Click `Customize` on your main theme
3. Mouse over a block of text on the page and then click the `+` button, or the `Add Block` button (**Don't** click `Add Section`).
4. From the dropdown, select `Custom HTML`
5. Paste this in the `HTML` field:

> ```
> <style>
>   nav * {
>     color: red !important;
>   }
> </style>
> ```